# How can I trim data from a value inside array?

Tags: php, arrays, json, string, replace

This is my data:

```
$d = $request->request->get('data');
```

The output:

```
[{"name":"form[id]","value":"10"},{"name":"form[name]","value":"Telefon2"},{"name":"form[uuid]","value":"bb80878ad4"},{"name":"form[productgroup]","value":"6"},{"name":"form[category]","value":"1"},{"name":"form[documents]","value":"7"}
```

I want to create a new array, that is removing extracting the variable inside the brackets.

```
 function trim($d) {
          preg_match('#\[(.*?)\]#', $d, $match);
          return $match[1];
   }


$dData = array_combine(array_column(trim($d), 'name'), array_column($d, 'value'));
$json = json_encode($dData);
```

But the error is

> Warning: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given

Comment: Isn't your output missing a `]` ? If it is then your output must be a `json`

Comment: Yes, sorry forgot one line

Comment: In that case I suggest you to use `json_decode()`

Comment: Why do you try regex at all? What is the expected `$json` result?

Comment: I neither understand why do you use `preg_match`. Did you consider using `array_map`?

Comment: @guyaloni Not yet. Harry Cartwright suggested a solution with preg_match, in combination with array_map, I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to need to do a few things before you begin.

Firstly, rename the `trim` function to something like `extract_name` because PHP already has a built in `trim` function that removes whitespace from a string - or any character present in the character mask.
Secondly, you are going to need to iterate over each of the elements in the name column. You will notice the error you are getting from `preg_match` is because you are passing all values in one go.
Thirdly, I am assuming that the value of `$d` is an array of PHP objects. This is done, and assumed, in my solution using `$d = json_decode($d);`.

Using `array_map` instead of a foreach means we can have a nice one liner:

```
function extract_name($d) {
    preg_match('#\[(.*?)\]#', $d, $match);
    return $match[1];
}

$dData = array_combine(array_map('extract_name', array_column($d, 'name')), array_column($d, 'value'));
```

The output being:

```
array:6 [
  "id" => "10"
  "name" => "Telefon2"
  "uuid" => "bb80878ad4"
  "productgroup" => "6"
  "category" => "1"
  "documents" => "7"
]
```

[Live demo](https://3v4l.org/MZq5D)

Comment: Thank you, this sounds like a good solution. I tested it but I get the error message `Warning: array_map() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'new_trim' not found or invalid function name`

Comment: @monkeylove I have updated the question. As I said in the answer, you need to rename your original function to be called `extract_name` and then it will work.

Comment: Yes, this is what is confusing me.. However I name it, the error message is: `Warning: array_map() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'extract_name' not found or invalid function name`

Comment: @monkeylove Are you sure you are copying this answer correctly? I have added a live demo to this answer to make it clearer what I think the poster was trying to accomplish.

Comment: @monkeylove Is the function declared in the same scope as `$dData`? Have you copied my snippet? The function must have the same name as a the string that you are passing to array_map. If that doesn't work, try creating an anonymous function instead and seeing if you are still having problems.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you need smth like this

````
$d = ['{"name":"form[id]","value":"10"}', '{"name":"form[name]","value":"Telefon2"}', '{"name":"form[uuid]","value":"bb80878ad4"}', '{"name":"form[productgroup]","value":"6"}'];

function combine(array $d): array
{
    $res = [];
    foreach ($d as $item) {
        $value = json_decode($item, true);
        preg_match('#\[(.*?)\]#', $value['name'], $match);;
        $columnName = $match[1];
        $res[$columnName] = $value['value'];
    }

    return $res;
}


$dData = combine($d);
$json = json_encode($dData);
echo $json;```
````